# Improve performance - if and for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My dataframe has around 12M rows, and I need to improve performance when using `for` loop, but I can't figure out how to do.
I'm using Python/Pandas which is working properly, but is extremely slow.

I need to have the colums `num_pr` and `num_pu` for every *timestamp* calculating from a sum of `TempTable` using the following conditions.

```
TempTable = pd.DataFrame({'account': np.arange(1, 2), 'pr': 0, 'pu': 0})
TempTable = TempTable.set_index('account')

df['num_pr'] = 0
df['num_pu'] = 0
for row in range(0, 10000):
    if (df.action[row] == 'SA' and df.status[row] == 'PR') or (df.action[row] == 'I' and df.status[row] == 'PR'):
        TempTable.loc[df.account[row], 'pr'] = 1
    elif (df.action[row] == 'SA' and df.status[row] == 'PU') or (df.action[row] == 'I' and df.status[row] == 'PU'):
        TempTable.loc[df.account[row], 'pu'] = 1
    elif (df.action[row] == 'SO' and df.status[row] == 'PR'):
        TempTable.loc[df.account[row], 'pr'] = 0
    elif (df.action[row] == 'SO' and df.status[row] == 'PU'):
        TempTable.loc[df.account[row], 'pu'] = 0
    df.loc[row, 'num_pr'] = TempTable.loc[:, 'pr'].sum()
    df.loc[row, 'num_pu'] = TempTable.loc[:, 'pu'].sum()


    account status  timestamp               status  num_pr      num_pu
0   1111111 SA      2018-06-28 02:00:01.024 PU      0           1
1   2222222 I       2018-06-28 02:00:02.032 PU      0           2
2   1111111 I       2018-06-28 02:00:03.382 PU      0           2
3   3333333 SO      2018-06-28 02:00:04.395 PR      0           2
4   1111111 I       2018-06-28 02:00:05.401 PU      0           2
5   1111111 I       2018-06-28 02:00:05.407 PU      0           2
6   2222222 I       2018-06-28 02:00:06.409 PU      0           2
7   3333333 SA      2018-06-28 02:00:06.413 PR      1           2
8   1111111 SO      2018-06-28 02:00:07.414 PU      1           1
9   3333333 SO      2018-06-28 02:00:07.467 PR      0           1
10  1111111 SA      2018-06-28 02:00:08.414 PR      1           1
```

Comment: At first glance you should be able to vectorize these operations instead of looping through all the rows, which would be much more efficient, but I'm not entirely understanding what you're trying to do.  Why not set `pr` and `pu` using an `apply` function instead of a loop?

Comment: I have to apply the if condition to the  row of data frame and sum the coloumn of pr/pu TempTable and report to num_pr/num_pu. Thanks

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({'account':[1111111,2222222,1111111,3333333,1111111,1111111,2222222,3333333,1111111,3333333,1111111], 'action':['SA','I','I','SO','I','I','I','SA','SO','SO','SA'], 'timestamp':['02:00:01.024','02:00:02.032','02:00:03.382','02:00:04.395','02:00:05.401','02:00:05.407','02:00:06.409','02:00:06.413','02:00:07.414','02:00:07.467','02:00:08.414'],'status': ['PU','PU','PU','PR','PU','PU','PU','PR','PU','PR','PR'],'num_pr': ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'], 'num_pu': ['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],})